# Indicator Panel / System Tray Missing after upgrade to 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, unity, 16.04, indicator, system-tray

My indicator panel / System Tray and calendar are missing from my Unity Desktop after upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.

Is there a command I can run, or some settings I can change to get those back?

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't the direct fix that I wanted using Unity, it does work...

If you run the following:

1. startx
2. Open a terminal
3. In the terminal type `gnome-panel &`
4. In the terminal type `compiz`

You will now have a clock, a tray, the applications menu, a taskbar, and borders you can drag your windows around with.